# Can't stop anchor jumping when using .html to replace a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen the ways to prevent jumping when using an event like click however I am not useing an event so it does not work for me. I am trying to replace a div with some retrieved information like so:

```
$.ajax({
        "data": {
            "action": 'some_action',
        },
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "text",
        "success": function(data) {
            var source = $('<div>' + data + '</div>');
            $('#id').html(source.find('#id').html());
        }
    });
```

My problem is that the page jumps to #id when the html replacement happens.

The code has been in place for years and only recently started, and it only seems to happen with chrome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281110/page-is-jumping-after-selector-htmlsome-content-in-google-chrome perhaps?

Comment: I gave that a shot before and it didn't help unfortunately. Thanks though!

Comment: probably the page becomes shorter after the update, try setting a min height on the body